# Clamav on Centos 8 installation

Tags: centos, clamav, centos8

I have installed ClamAV on Centos 8, following the installation guide on their website.

I have run freshclam and that works fine but if I try to do a scan I get the following error:

```
clamdscan /home
ERROR: Could not connect to clamd on LocalSocket /tmp/clamd.socket: No such file or directory

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 0
Total errors: 1
Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
```

I have tried following many suggestions online for different LocalSocket files but they all yield the same result or worse.

This is my config file

```
##
## Example config file for the Clam AV daemon
## Please read the clamd.conf(5) manual before editing this file.
##


# Uncomment this option to enable logging.
# LogFile must be writable for the user running daemon.
# A full path is required.
# Default: disabled
LogFile /tmp/clamd.log

# By default the log file is locked for writing - the lock protects against
# running clamd multiple times (if want to run another clamd, please
# copy the configuration file, change the LogFile variable, and run
# the daemon with --config-file option).
# This option disables log file locking.
# Default: no
#LogFileUnlock yes

# Maximum size of the log file.
# Value of 0 disables the limit.
# You may use 'M' or 'm' for megabytes (1M = 1m = 1048576 bytes)
# and 'K' or 'k' for kilobytes (1K = 1k = 1024 bytes). To specify the size
# in bytes just don't use modifiers. If LogFileMaxSize is enabled, log
# rotation (the LogRotate option) will always be enabled.
# Default: 1M
LogFileMaxSize 10M

# Log time with each message.
# Default: no
LogTime yes

# Also log clean files. Useful in debugging but drastically increases the
# log size.
# Default: no
#LogClean yes

# Use system logger (can work together with LogFile).
# Default: no
#LogSyslog yes

# Specify the type of syslog messages - please refer to 'man syslog'
# for facility names.
# Default: LOG_LOCAL6
#LogFacility LOG_MAIL

# Enable verbose logging.
# Default: no
LogVerbose yes

# Enable log rotation. Always enabled when LogFileMaxSize is enabled.
# Default: no
#LogRotate yes

# Enable Prelude output.
# Default: no
#PreludeEnable yes
#
# Set the name of the analyzer used by prelude-admin.
# Default: ClamAV
#PreludeAnalyzerName ClamAV

# Log additional information about the infected file, such as its
# size and hash, together with the virus name.
#ExtendedDetectionInfo yes

# This option allows you to save a process identifier of the listening
# daemon (main thread).
# Default: disabled
#PidFile /var/run/clamd.pid

# Optional path to the global temporary directory.
# Default: system specific (usually /tmp or /var/tmp).
#TemporaryDirectory /var/tmp

# Path to the database directory.
# Default: hardcoded (depends on installation options)
#DatabaseDirectory /var/lib/clamav

# Only load the official signatures published by the ClamAV project.
# Default: no
#OfficialDatabaseOnly no

# The daemon can work in local mode, network mode or both.
# Due to security reasons we recommend the local mode.

# Path to a local socket file the daemon will listen on.
# Default: disabled (must be specified by a user)
LocalSocket /tmp/clamd.socket


# Sets the group ownership on the unix socket.
# Default: disabled (the primary group of the user running clam
#LocalSocketGroup clamav

# Sets the permissions on the unix socket to the specified mode.
# Default: disabled (socket is world accessible)
LocalSocketMode 660

# Remove stale socket after unclean shutdown.
# Default: yes
#FixStaleSocket yes

# TCP port address.
# Default: no
#TCPSocket 3310

# TCP address.
# By default we bind to INADDR_ANY, probably not wise.
# Enable the following to provide some degree of protection
# from the outside world. This option can be specified multiple
# times if you want to listen on multiple IPs. IPv6 is now supported.
# Default: no
#TCPAddr 127.0.0.1

# Maximum length the queue of pending connections may grow to.
# Default: 200
#MaxConnectionQueueLength 30

# Clamd uses FTP-like protocol to receive data from remote clients.
# If you are using clamav-milter to balance load between remote clamd daemons
# on firewall servers you may need to tune the options below.

# Close the connection when the data size limit is exceeded.
# The value should match your MTA's limit for a maximum attachment size.
# Default: 25M
#StreamMaxLength 10M

# Limit port range.
# Default: 1024
#StreamMinPort 30000
# Default: 2048
#StreamMaxPort 32000

# Maximum number of threads running at the same time.
# Default: 10
#MaxThreads 20

# Waiting for data from a client socket will timeout after this time (seconds).
# Default: 120
#ReadTimeout 300

# This option specifies the time (in seconds) after which clamd should
# timeout if a client doesn't provide any initial command after connecting.
# Default: 30
#CommandReadTimeout 30

# This option specifies how long to wait (in milliseconds) if the send buffer
# is full.
# Keep this value low to prevent clamd hanging.
#
# Default: 500
#SendBufTimeout 200

# Maximum number of queued items (including those being processed by
# MaxThreads threads).
# It is recommended to have this value at least twice MaxThreads if possible.
# WARNING: you shouldn't increase this too much to avoid running out  of file
# descriptors, the following condition should hold:
# MaxThreads*MaxRecursion + (MaxQueue - MaxThreads) + 6< RLIMIT_NOFILE (usual
# max is 1024).
#
# Default: 100
#MaxQueue 200

# Waiting for a new job will timeout after this time (seconds).
# Default: 30
#IdleTimeout 60

# Don't scan files and directories matching regex
# This directive can be used multiple times
# Default: scan all
#ExcludePath ^/proc/
#ExcludePath ^/sys/

# Maximum depth directories are scanned at.
# Default: 15
#MaxDirectoryRecursion 20

# Follow directory symlinks.
# Default: no
#FollowDirectorySymlinks yes

# Follow regular file symlinks.
# Default: no
#FollowFileSymlinks yes

# Scan files and directories on other filesystems.
# Default: yes
#CrossFilesystems yes

# Perform a database check.
# Default: 600 (10 min)
#SelfCheck 600

# Execute a command when virus is found. In the command string %v will
# be replaced with the virus name.
# Default: no
#VirusEvent /usr/local/bin/send_sms 123456789 "VIRUS ALERT: %v"

# Run as another user (clamd must be started by root for this option to work)
# Default: don't drop privileges
User clamscan

# Stop daemon when libclamav reports out of memory condition.
#ExitOnOOM yes

# Don't fork into background.
# Default: no
#Foreground yes

# Enable debug messages in libclamav.
# Default: no
#Debug yes

# Do not remove temporary files (for debug purposes).
# Default: no
#LeaveTemporaryFiles yes

# Permit use of the ALLMATCHSCAN command. If set to no, clamd will reject
# any ALLMATCHSCAN command as invalid.
# Default: yes
#AllowAllMatchScan no

# Detect Possibly Unwanted Applications.
# Default: no
#DetectPUA yes

# Exclude a specific PUA category. This directive can be used multiple times.
# See https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-faq/blob/master/faq/faq-pua.md for
# the complete list of PUA categories.
# Default: Load all categories (if DetectPUA is activated)
#ExcludePUA NetTool
#ExcludePUA PWTool

# Only include a specific PUA category. This directive can be used multiple
# times.
# Default: Load all categories (if DetectPUA is activated)
#IncludePUA Spy
#IncludePUA Scanner
#IncludePUA RAT

# This option causes memory or nested map scans to dump the content to disk.
# If you turn on this option, more data is written to disk and is available
# when the LeaveTemporaryFiles option is enabled.
#ForceToDisk yes

# This option allows you to disable the caching feature of the engine. By
# default, the engine will store an MD5 in a cache of any files that are
# not flagged as virus or that hit limits checks. Disabling the cache will
# have a negative performance impact on large scans.
# Default: no
#DisableCache yes

# In some cases (eg. complex malware, exploits in graphic files, and others),
# ClamAV uses special algorithms to detect abnormal patterns and behaviors that
# may be malicious.  This option enables alerting on such heuristically
# detected potential threats.
# Default: yes
#HeuristicAlerts yes

# Allow heuristic alerts to take precedence.
# When enabled, if a heuristic scan (such as phishingScan) detects
# a possible virus/phish it will stop scan immediately. Recommended, saves CPU
# scan-time.
# When disabled, virus/phish detected by heuristic scans will be reported only
# at the end of a scan. If an archive contains both a heuristically detected
# virus/phish, and a real malware, the real malware will be reported
#
# Keep this disabled if you intend to handle "*.Heuristics.*" viruses
# differently from "real" malware.
# If a non-heuristically-detected virus (signature-based) is found first,
# the scan is interrupted immediately, regardless of this config option.
#
# Default: no
#HeuristicScanPrecedence yes


##
## Heuristic Alerts
##

# With this option clamav will try to detect broken executables (both PE and
# ELF) and alert on them with the Broken.Executable heuristic signature.
# Default: no
#AlertBrokenExecutables yes

# Alert on encrypted archives _and_ documents with heuristic signature
# (encrypted .zip, .7zip, .rar, .pdf).
# Default: no
#AlertEncrypted yes

# Alert on encrypted archives with heuristic signature (encrypted .zip, .7zip,
# .rar).
# Default: no
#AlertEncryptedArchive yes

# Alert on encrypted archives with heuristic signature (encrypted .pdf).
# Default: no
#AlertEncryptedDoc yes

# With this option enabled OLE2 files containing VBA macros, which were not
# detected by signatures will be marked as "Heuristics.OLE2.ContainsMacros".
# Default: no
#AlertOLE2Macros yes

# Alert on SSL mismatches in URLs, even if the URL isn't in the database.
# This can lead to false positives.
# Default: no
#AlertPhishingSSLMismatch yes

# Alert on cloaked URLs, even if URL isn't in database.
# This can lead to false positives.
# Default: no
#AlertPhishingCloak yes

# Alert on raw DMG image files containing partition intersections
# Default: no
#AlertPartitionIntersection yes


##
## Executable files
##

# PE stands for Portable Executable - it's an executable file format used
# in all 32 and 64-bit versions of Windows operating systems. This option
# allows ClamAV to perform a deeper analysis of executable files and it's also
# required for decompression of popular executable packers such as UPX, FSG,
# and Petite. If you turn off this option, the original files will still be
# scanned, but without additional processing.
# Default: yes
#ScanPE yes

# Certain PE files contain an authenticode signature. By default, we check
# the signature chain in the PE file against a database of trusted and
# revoked certificates if the file being scanned is marked as a virus.
# If any certificate in the chain validates against any trusted root, but
# does not match any revoked certificate, the file is marked as whitelisted.
# If the file does match a revoked certificate, the file is marked as virus.
# The following setting completely turns off authenticode verification.
# Default: no
#DisableCertCheck yes

# Executable and Linking Format is a standard format for UN*X executables.
# This option allows you to control the scanning of ELF files.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without additional processing.
# Default: yes
#ScanELF yes


##
## Documents
##

# This option enables scanning of OLE2 files, such as Microsoft Office
# documents and .msi files.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without additional processing.
# Default: yes
#ScanOLE2 yes

# This option enables scanning within PDF files.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without decoding and additional processing.
# Default: yes
#ScanPDF yes

# This option enables scanning within SWF files.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without decoding and additional processing.
# Default: yes
#ScanSWF yes

# This option enables scanning xml-based document files supported by libclamav.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without additional processing.
# Default: yes
#ScanXMLDOCS yes

# This option enables scanning of HWP3 files.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without additional processing.
# Default: yes
#ScanHWP3 yes


##
## Mail files
##

# Enable internal e-mail scanner.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without parsing individual messages/attachments.
# Default: yes
ScanMail yes

# Scan RFC1341 messages split over many emails.
# You will need to periodically clean up $TemporaryDirectory/clamav-partial
# directory.
# WARNING: This option may open your system to a DoS attack.
#      Never use it on loaded servers.
# Default: no
#ScanPartialMessages yes

# With this option enabled ClamAV will try to detect phishing attempts by using
# HTML.Phishing and Email.Phishing NDB signatures.
# Default: yes
#PhishingSignatures no

# With this option enabled ClamAV will try to detect phishing attempts by
# analyzing URLs found in emails using WDB and PDB signature databases.
# Default: yes
#PhishingScanURLs no


##
## Data Loss Prevention (DLP)
##

# Enable the DLP module
# Default: No
#StructuredDataDetection yes

# This option sets the lowest number of Credit Card numbers found in a file
# to generate a detect.
# Default: 3
#StructuredMinCreditCardCount 5

# This option sets the lowest number of Social Security Numbers found
# in a file to generate a detect.
# Default: 3
#StructuredMinSSNCount 5

# With this option enabled the DLP module will search for valid
# SSNs formatted as xxx-yy-zzzz
# Default: yes
#StructuredSSNFormatNormal yes

# With this option enabled the DLP module will search for valid
# SSNs formatted as xxxyyzzzz
# Default: no
#StructuredSSNFormatStripped yes


##
## HTML
##

# Perform HTML normalisation and decryption of MS Script Encoder code.
# Default: yes
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without additional processing.
#ScanHTML yes


##
## Archives
##

# ClamAV can scan within archives and compressed files.
# If you turn off this option, the original files will still be scanned, but
# without unpacking and additional processing.
# Default: yes
#ScanArchive yes


##
## Limits
##

# The options below protect your system against Denial of Service attacks
# using archive bombs.

# This option sets the maximum amount of time to a scan may take.
# In this version, this field only affects the scan time of ZIP archives.
# Value of 0 disables the limit.
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result allow scanning
# of certain files to lock up the scanning process/threads resulting in a
# Denial of Service.
# Time is in milliseconds.
# Default: 120000
#MaxScanTime 300000

# This option sets the maximum amount of data to be scanned for each input
# file. Archives and other containers are recursively extracted and scanned
# up to this value.
# Value of 0 disables the limit
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 100M
#MaxScanSize 150M

# Files larger than this limit won't be scanned. Affects the input file itself
# as well as files contained inside it (when the input file is an archive, a
# document or some other kind of container).
# Value of 0 disables the limit.
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 25M
#MaxFileSize 30M

# Nested archives are scanned recursively, e.g. if a Zip archive contains a RAR
# file, all files within it will also be scanned. This options specifies how
# deeply the process should be continued.
# Note: setting this limit too high may result in severe damage to the system.
# Default: 16
#MaxRecursion 10

# Number of files to be scanned within an archive, a document, or any other
# container file.
# Value of 0 disables the limit.
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 10000
#MaxFiles 15000

# Maximum size of a file to check for embedded PE. Files larger than this value
# will skip the additional analysis step.
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 10M
#MaxEmbeddedPE 10M

# Maximum size of a HTML file to normalize. HTML files larger than this value
# will not be normalized or scanned.
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 10M
#MaxHTMLNormalize 10M

# Maximum size of a normalized HTML file to scan. HTML files larger than this
# value after normalization will not be scanned.
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 2M
#MaxHTMLNoTags 2M

# Maximum size of a script file to normalize. Script content larger than this
# value will not be normalized or scanned.
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 5M
#MaxScriptNormalize 5M

# Maximum size of a ZIP file to reanalyze type recognition. ZIP files larger
# than this value will skip the step to potentially reanalyze as PE.
# Note: disabling this limit or setting it too high may result in severe damage
# to the system.
# Default: 1M
#MaxZipTypeRcg 1M

# This option sets the maximum number of partitions of a raw disk image to be
# scanned.
# Raw disk images with more partitions than this value will have up to
# the value number partitions scanned. Negative values are not allowed.
# Note: setting this limit too high may result in severe damage or impact
# performance.
# Default: 50
#MaxPartitions 128

# This option sets the maximum number of icons within a PE to be scanned.
# PE files with more icons than this value will have up to the value number
# icons scanned.
# Negative values are not allowed.
# WARNING: setting this limit too high may result in severe damage or impact
# performance.
# Default: 100
#MaxIconsPE 200

# This option sets the maximum recursive calls for HWP3 parsing during
# scanning. HWP3 files using more than this limit will be terminated and
# alert the user.
# Scans will be unable to scan any HWP3 attachments if the recursive limit
# is reached.
# Negative values are not allowed.
# WARNING: setting this limit too high may result in severe damage or impact
# performance.
# Default: 16
#MaxRecHWP3 16

# This option sets the maximum calls to the PCRE match function during
# an instance of regex matching.
# Instances using more than this limit will be terminated and alert the user
# but the scan will continue.
# For more information on match_limit, see the PCRE documentation.
# Negative values are not allowed.
# WARNING: setting this limit too high may severely impact performance.
# Default: 100000
#PCREMatchLimit 20000

# This option sets the maximum recursive calls to the PCRE match function
# during an instance of regex matching.
# Instances using more than this limit will be terminated and alert the user
# but the scan will continue.
# For more information on match_limit_recursion, see the PCRE documentation.
# Negative values are not allowed and values > PCREMatchLimit are superfluous.
# WARNING: setting this limit too high may severely impact performance.
# Default: 2000
#PCRERecMatchLimit 10000

# This option sets the maximum filesize for which PCRE subsigs will be
# executed. Files exceeding this limit will not have PCRE subsigs executed
# unless a subsig is encompassed to a smaller buffer.
# Negative values are not allowed.
# Setting this value to zero disables the limit.
# WARNING: setting this limit too high or disabling it may severely impact
# performance.
# Default: 25M
#PCREMaxFileSize 100M

# When AlertExceedsMax is set, files exceeding the MaxFileSize, MaxScanSize, or
# MaxRecursion limit will be flagged with the virus
# "Heuristics.Limits.Exceeded".
# Default: no
#AlertExceedsMax yes

##
## On-access Scan Settings
##

# Don't scan files larger than OnAccessMaxFileSize
# Value of 0 disables the limit.
# Default: 5M
#OnAccessMaxFileSize 10M

# Max number of scanning threads to allocate to the OnAccess thread pool at
# startup. These threads are the ones responsible for creating a connection
# with the daemon and kicking off scanning after an event has been processed.
# To prevent clamonacc from consuming all clamd's resources keep this lower
# than clamd's max threads.
# Default: 5
#OnAccessMaxThreads 10

# Max amount of time (in milliseconds) that the OnAccess client should spend
# for every connect, send, and recieve attempt when communicating with clamd
# via curl.
# Default: 5000 (5 seconds)
# OnAccessCurlTimeout 10000

# Toggles dynamic directory determination. Allows for recursively watching
# include paths.
# Default: no
#OnAccessDisableDDD yes

# Set the include paths (all files inside them will be scanned). You can have
# multiple OnAccessIncludePath directives but each directory must be added
# in a separate line.
# Default: disabled
#OnAccessIncludePath /home
#OnAccessIncludePath /students

# Set the exclude paths. All subdirectories are also excluded.
# Default: disabled
#OnAccessExcludePath /home/user

# Modifies fanotify blocking behaviour when handling permission events.
# If off, fanotify will only notify if the file scanned is a virus,
# and not perform any blocking.
# Default: no
#OnAccessPrevention yes

# When using prevention, if this option is turned on, any errors that occur
# during scanning will result in the event attempt being denied. This could
# potentially lead to unwanted system behaviour with certain configurations,
# so the client defaults this to off and prefers allowing access events in
# case of scan or connection error.
# Default: no
#OnAccessDenyOnError yes

# Toggles extra scanning and notifications when a file or directory is
# created or moved.
# Requires the  DDD system to kick-off extra scans.
# Default: no
#OnAccessExtraScanning yes

# Set the  mount point to be scanned. The mount point specified, or the mount
# point containing the specified directory will be watched. If any directories
# are specified, this option will preempt (disable and ignore all options
# related to) the DDD system. This option will result in verdicts only.
# Note that prevention is explicitly disallowed to prevent common, fatal
# misconfigurations. (e.g. watching "/" with prevention on and no exclusions
# made on vital system directories)
# It can be used multiple times.
# Default: disabled
#OnAccessMountPath /
#OnAccessMountPath /home/user

# With this option you can whitelist the root UID (0). Processes run under
# root with be able to access all files without triggering scans or
# permission denied events.
# Note that if clamd cannot check the uid of the process that generated an
# on-access scan event (e.g., because OnAccessPrevention was not enabled, and
# the process already exited), clamd will perform a scan.  Thus, setting
# OnAccessExcludeRootUID is not *guaranteed* to prevent every access by the
# root user from triggering a scan (unless OnAccessPrevention is enabled).
# Default: no
#OnAccessExcludeRootUID no

# With this option you can whitelist specific UIDs. Processes with these UIDs
# will be able to access all files without triggering scans or permission
# denied events.
# This option can be used multiple times (one per line).
# Using a value of 0 on any line will disable this option entirely.
# To whitelist the root UID (0) please enable the OnAccessExcludeRootUID
# option.
# Also note that if clamd cannot check the uid of the process that generated an
# on-access scan event (e.g., because OnAccessPrevention was not enabled, and
# the process already exited), clamd will perform a scan.  Thus, setting
```

Additionally clamd@scan will not start:

```
systemctl status clamd@scan.service
● clamd@scan.service - clamd scanner (scan) daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/clamd@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-03-20 16:43:51 GMT; 14s ago
  Process: 1851 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/clamd --foreground=yes (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 1851 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mar 20 16:43:51 server.com systemd[1]: clamd@scan.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Mar 20 16:43:51 server.com systemd[1]: clamd@scan.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 20 16:43:51 server.com systemd[1]: clamd@scan.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Mar 20 16:43:51 server.com systemd[1]: clamd@scan.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mar 20 16:43:51 server.com systemd[1]: Stopped clamd scanner (scan) daemon.
Mar 20 16:43:51 server.com systemd[1]: clamd@scan.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 20 16:43:51 server.com systemd[1]: clamd@scan.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 20 16:43:51 server.com systemd[1]: Failed to start clamd scanner (scan) daemon.
```

Comment: All working now, what a pain

Comment: You can yes, btw I also had to create a system unit for clamd in /usr/lib/systemd/system with ExecStart = /usr/local/sbin/clamd. At least I learnt some more Linux admin today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some solutions mentioned in the ["clamd will not start"](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/clamd-will-not-start.34559/) post, that may help with solving this "`ERROR: Could not connect to clamd on LocalSocket`" issue.

**One solution mentions** to ensure both these lines in the config file are not commented out

```
LocalSocket /tmp/clamd.socket
FixStaleSocket yes
```

To also run these commands

```
mkdir /var/run/clamd
chown root:<same group name that clamd runs as> /var/run/clamd
```

Then restart the `clamd` services and also consider updating to the latest version of ClamAV via `yum`.

Additionally the OP created a system unit for clamd in `/usr/lib/systemd/system` with `ExecStart = /usr/local/sbin/clamd`.

Furthermore, it is mentioned to also run `cat /etc/passwd` to see permissions of the clamav user and to change permissions back to the clamav user.

```
chown -R clamav.clamav /var/log/clamav/
chown -R clamav.clamav /var/run/clamav/
chown -R clamav.clamav /var/lib/clamav/
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Clamd will not start](https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/clamd-will-not-start.34559/)
- [10.6. CREATING AND MODIFYING SYSTEMD UNIT FILES](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files)